# How to run a git filter-branch in groovy

Tags: git, groovy, git-filter-branch

I have a groovy script that I am using to run several git commands. It works perfectly, except for one command which is a filter-branch command.

This is the function I am using to run git cli commands:

```
private static runProc(closure) {
    def output = new StringBuffer()
    def p = closure.call()
    p.waitForProcessOutput(output, System.err)
    println output.toString()

return output.toString()
```

}

And here is an example of how it is called:

```
runProc({
    new ProcessBuilder("git", "add", "--all").directory(sourceLocation).start()
})
```

This is the command that I need to run in this script:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter \
    'if [ $GIT_COMMIT = 20fbf7f4cd361402d9fef1ecaecc1461173c8 ]
     then
         export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Fri May 8 21:38:53 2019 -0800"
         export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Sat Jun 13 01:01:01 2019 -0700"
     fi' -f
```

It changes the commit date of the most recent commit in the current branch. THIS COMMAND WORKS in a regular terminal. I've used it loads of times, but I've decided to try and automate this process by putting it in a script.

Here is my first attempt at running this in groovy:

```
runProc({
    new ProcessBuilder("git", "filter-branch", "--env-filter \'if [ \$GIT_COMMIT = ${commit_hash} ] then export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=\"Fri May 8 21:38:53 2019 -0800\" export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=\"Sat Jun 13 01:01:01 2019 -0700\" fi\'"
    ).directory(sourceLocation).start()
})
```

This gives the following error:

```
usage: git filter-branch [--setup <command>] [--subdirectory-filter <directory>] [--env-filter <command>]
    [--tree-filter <command>] [--index-filter <command>]
    [--parent-filter <command>] [--msg-filter <command>]
    [--commit-filter <command>] [--tag-name-filter <command>]
    [--original <namespace>]
    [-d <directory>] [-f | --force] [--state-branch <branch>]
    [--] [<rev-list options>...]
```

I tried several different ways of tokenizing this, but I can't seem to get it to work. So, I tried another method:

```
def proc = "git filter-branch -f --env-filter \'if [ \$GIT_COMMIT = $commit_hash ] then export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=\"Fri May 8 21:38:53 2018 -0800\" export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=\"Sat Jun 13 01:01:01 2018 -0700\" fi\' -- $sourceLocation".execute()
def b = new StringBuffer()
proc.waitForProcessOutput(b, System.err)
println b.toString()
```

Originally, when I was running this without the -- $sourceLocation on the end, I was getting an error that $GIT_COMMIT was not present in the working tree. Now, I am getting this error:

```
Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.
```

My working tree is clean. I have fetched, pulled, stash drop'd, reset HEAD, absolutely everything. None of these commits have any content either. I am simply using touch to create a file and adding that, then committing. As far as I can tell, there are no unstaged changes and this error is being caused by something else.

What is the best way to run this command using groovy? I would really prefer it if I could use the processBuilder method, since it is what I'm doing for all of the other commands, and I know it can work. I think it's an issue of how I am tokenizing the command.

EDIT---------

Now, the date of the commit doesn't change, and the output is as follows:

```
Rewrite 5e6d6b35c8d5aa0f05518c39a4a06fb4ce1551d7 (1/2) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    
Rewrite 3623fea155f79f3cee7e771d516c4d511109b72f (2/2) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    
Ref 'refs/heads/feature844501/current_dates_devops' was rewritten
```

The output should look like this:

```
Rewrite 3623fea155f79f3cee7e771d516c4d511109b72f (2/2) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted) 
Ref 'refs/heads/feature844501/current_dates_devops' was rewritten
```

For some reason, it has this hash: `5e6d6b35c8d5aa0f05518c39a4a06fb4ce1551d7`
every time as output 1/2, then the correct one for 2/2

Comment: The output just shows the `commits` you have, so no worries about that. If you don'w want it as output, you can simply skip that as i added in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I always suggests to use `ProcessBuilder`. You can use `"""` in groovy for String with multi lines.

The code shown below works,

```
String commit_hash ='20fbf7f4cd361402d9fef1ecaecc1461173c8'
String filterString = """if [ \$GIT_COMMIT = $commit_hash ]
then 
        export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Fri May 8 21:38:53 2019 -0800"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Sat Jun 13 01:01:01 2019 -0700"
fi"""


def proc = new ProcessBuilder("git", "filter-branch", '--env-filter', "$filterString", "-f").directory(new File("/home/bhanuchander/cygdsl")).start()
def b = new StringBuffer()
proc.waitForProcessOutput(b, System.err)
println b.toString()
```

**Edit : 1**

If you don't want all result. you can skip to the last **2 lines**. Using the script below,

```
def proc = new ProcessBuilder("git", "filter-branch", '--env-filter', "$filterString", "-f").directory(new File("/home/bhanuchander/cygdsl")).start()
def result =  proc.in.readLines()
println result.drop(result.size()-3).join("\n")
proc.waitFor()
```

Comment: This is excellent. The command runs,  however it is not doing what I expect. In the terminal it works fine, but running it from groovy seems to use the wrong hash halfway through. I've amended my question with an explanation of this

Comment: @ConnorSchwinghammer It is a normal thing. If you want the last lines of the `stream` you can change the code as i mentioned in **Edit 1**.

Comment: The problem is it isn't actually changing the date of the commit. It changes it if i run the command in terminal, but not via groovy